# c++ breaking circular dependencie for sort algorithm object

Tags: c++, g++, circular-dependency

i have two classes A and B

A.hpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "B.hpp"

class A {
public:
  void sortTrans() { std::sort(trans_.begin(), trans_.end(), sortStruct); }
  unsigned int name() { return name_; }
private:
  std::vector<B*> trans_;
  unsigned int name_;
};
```

B.hpp:

```
class A;

class B {
  A& source_;
  A& dest_;
  unsigned int choice_;
};
```

Now I want to sort trans_ by the values of choice and name, therefore i wrote

```
struct sort {
  bool operator()(B* t1, B* t2) {
    if (t1->choice < t2->choice)
        return true;
    if (t1->dest_.name() < t2->dest_.name())
        return true;
    return false;
  }
} sortStruct;
```

But now I'm facing a problem to break the circular dependency. The definition of A is in A.hpp and the one of B in B.hpp. In B.hpp I use a forward decleration of A and A includes B.hpp. But where (or how) do i have to put the sortStruct, since it uses the definition of either, A and B. And I'm always getting the error

```
Wrong usage of forward declaration A
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you show us the entire content of A.hpp and B.hpp including forward declarations

Comment: I am not sure, but will [this help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) ??

Comment: Your `B` doesn't have the `attr1` and `attr2` methods you're calling, and your `sort::operator()` doesn't refer to A at all. What does your actual code look like, and what line is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: also tell which compiler, which line. It helps!

Comment: sorry for the typos, Class A has a attribute name and class B has a attribute choice. By those two I want so sort. g++ 4.6.3. The error is always about the line if (t1->dest_.name() < t2->dest_.name())
        return true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both headers can use forward declation, since neither really (needs to) depend on the other.

A.hpp

```
#ifndef A_HPP
#define A_HPP
#include <vector>

class B;

class A {
public:
  void sortTrans();
  unsigned name();
private:
  std::vector<B*> trans_;
  unsigned int attr1_;
  unsigned int attr2_;
};
#endif
```

B.hpp

```
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP_
class A;

class B {
  A& source_;
  A& dest_;
  unsigned choice_;
};
#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

// I can't really define this with your B as given ...
struct SortB {
    bool operator()(B *x, B *y) {
        if (x->choice_ < y->choice_)
            return true;
        if (x->dest_.name() < y->dest_.name())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
 };

void A::sortTrans()
{
    std::sort(trans_.begin(), trans_.end(), SortB());
}
```

Note I still haven't shown how B::choice_ and B::dest_ are accessed, because this is a design decision and I don't have enough information to make a good guess.

You can either expose them as public (in which case `B` is basically a struct), add accessor members to `B`, or forward-declare `SortB` in B.hpp as a friend.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I had a typo in my question that eliminated the dependency. I corrected it now.

Comment: OK - you can trivially implement that in the `SortB` above with no circular dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Works exactly as it is supposed to. To access dest_, source_ and choice_ in B I use accessor functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can put declaration of the `operator()` to the `B.hpp` and implementation - to the `B.cpp` (as usual)

```
// B.hpp
class A;

class B {
  A& source_;
  A& dest_;
};

SortB {
  bool operator()(B* a, B* b); // can be implemented in B.cpp
};
```

Nothing in implementation of the `SortB` need to know about `class A`:

```
// B.cpp
bool SortB::operator()(B* t1, B* t2) {
    if (t1->attr1() < t2->attr1())
        return true;
    if (t1->attr2() < t2->attr2())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Code in `A.hpp` doesn't need to be changed much:

```
// A.hpp
#include "B.hpp"

class A {
public:
  void sortTrans() { std::sort(trans_.begin(), trans_.end(), SortB()); }
private:
  std::vector<B*> trans_;
  unsigned int attr1_;
  unsigned int attr2_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if a class has a reference member, you need to provide constructor/copy constructor. Did you provide it for B

Also noticed that `t1->attr2()` < `t2->attr2()` isn't correct. It should be `t1->attr1_` and `t2->attr2_`

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function is probably not what you intended. It should probably be something like

```
if (b1->choice < b2->choice)
    return true;
if (b1->choice == b2->choice && b1->name < b2->name)
    return true;
return false;
```

If you don't have a == operator for choice you have to use the < operator reversed and negated to accomplish the same functionality